# Filter by both values on group by

Tags: r

I would like to filter 2 matching values of a column based on a group by condition. For example, from a patients dataset, I should match on both VisitType 1 and 2 grouped by patient ID.

So far, I am using following code.

```
patients %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% filter(VisitType == "6" and VisitType == "7")
```

This however does not return anything (which I guess is because VisitType 6 and 7 are different rows). Is there a way of filtering such that I get something like below:

```
PatientID     VisitType 
1                6
1                7
39               6
39               7
```

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(patients)`

Comment: Looks like you want to know if "6" and "7" are both in the VisitType column within a group. How about `filter("6" %in% VisitType, "7" %in% VisitType)` ?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of your data and desired output **for that sample data**. People are trying to help you, but we can't unless you give us enough to test your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `group_by()` just filter and and arrange if it won't already be in the form want.

```r
patients %>%
  filter(VisitType %in% c(6,7)) %>%
  arrange(PatientID) # optional
```

If you want to only see patients that have both `VisitType == 6 && VisitType == 7` then you would do something like

```r
patients %>%
  filter(VisitType %in% c(6,7)) %>%
  group_by(PatientID) %>%
  filter(n() >= 2)
```

Comment: This however also selects for cases that have only 6 or 7. I would like to see for all patients that have both 6 and 7 as the visit type. Do you suggest a code modification?

Comment: The edited answer will still break if a PatientID contains 6 but not 7 (for example, 6 and 8)

Comment: @Frank All I can think about is how much time has been wasted on this question because won't post a reprex of their data.

Comment: @sparkh2o See answer now. It's a little more verbose than I'd like but really impossible to know without seeing your data.